# Why does this jQuery work as a fiddle but not on my web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I've for this fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/hgGfw/ ) , I've been following a slider tutorial and that's the code I've got. It's using a self invoking function ( I think that's what it's called??). Anyway, It works with the jQuery set to "onLoad" on the fiddle, but when it's on my server it does nothing until it's wrapped in $(document).ready(.... script. Why is that? JSLint also moans about this;

```
( direction === 'next' ) ? ++current : --current;
```

Any idea why? My PHP isn't bad, so I know the syntax for that statement and it looks fine to me.

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: So, it *does* work, but you wonder why you need `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: jsfiddle wraps your script code with $(window).load automatically..

Comment: You can't process the DOM until all elements are loaded. That is why the .ready() function is there. If you try to manipulate elements of the DOM before they're ready then you'll get unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place javascript / jquery into the `JavaScript` panel of a http://jsfiddle.net, it will automatically place your code into a `$(window).load(function(){ }` block (when the Framework dropdown is set to `onLoad` and a `jQuery` option).

If you have a look at the **frame source** of the result pane, you should see this is the case.

With regards to why JSLint doesn't like the command, I *guess* it is expecting an assignment (despite the fact that you are doing incrementation/decrementation on the `current` variable).

If you assign the value to a variable, JSLint is happy.  I.e...

```
var tempVar = ( direction === 'next' ) ? ++current : --current;
```

Comment: or better: current += direction === 'next' ? 1 : -1;

Comment: Very true, @Michal, but I was trying give an idea why JSLint might be complaining, rather than trying to come up with a better idea... although point taken

Comment: Thanks for your input everyone!

@freefaller, is using that operator actually "wrong"? I took this code from a lesson on tuts plus, which is (?) supposed to be good stuff. I just want to learn as fast as possible, I don't mind how : )

Comment: @Dan, no it is NOT "wrong" - as far as I'm concerned (and aware) the syntax you have used is absolutely fine. *Normally* you'd assign the result of a ternary operator, and JSLint is obviously assuming that is always the case. However, as you've found, it isn't always the case  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect JSLint is complaining because the ternary operator is intended to select a value for an expression, rather than select an execution path.

Here you've used it as shorthand for an 'if' statement, which will work but is a little unusual.